# Checking NAN & Spaces for a given column list in Pandas Data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a beginner to Python and pandas ,I need to filter rows when a given columns/column  in the list  is spaces or Nulls or Nan

[image]

My result should be like this

[image]

Rejection rows:-

[image]

I am storing the keys in a list for this data frame in cols_list.

cols_list = ['Product_ID','Vendor_ID']

To remove Nans:

```
df2 = df.dropna(axis = 0, subset = cols_list, how = 'all', inplace = True)
```

but I would like to remove rows if both keys have spaces or either one has spaces too.
also i would like to capture the dropped rows in to another data frame .

```
df2 = df[df[cols_list].isna()]
```

Can any one please advise to check for spaces as well as Nan and remove those rows and capture the same . Since isna is not getting any of rows.Please advise and help.

Comment: First `replace('', float('nan'))`. Or use boolean indexing `m = df[cols].isna().any(axis=1) | df[cols].eq('').any(axis=1) ; print(df[~m]) ; print(df[m])`

Comment: I am trying to apply this

Comment: Sir, I am getting empty dataframe.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible input (not images)

Comment: Hi @mozway , could you please specific ,  i couldn't understand your question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Hi @mozway, please find the code which i tried but having said ,  i couldn't able to select rows which has Nan in respective columns in cols_list

Comment: df_nonull[cols_list] = df_nonull[cols_list].replace([' '],float('Nan'))

Comment: df_suc_rec=df_nonull.dropna(subset=cols_list,how='any')

Comment: df_rej_rec=df[df_nonull[cols_list].isnull()]  - not giving expected rows , it just display all records with Nan

Comment: df_rej_rec=df[df_nonull['Product_ID'].isnull() | df_nonull['Vendor_ID'].isnull()]

but i have this columns in the list ,

i need to pass this list in the dataframe to select all rows which has both columns  or either one of columns is Nan
Please advise.

Comment: Hi @mozway, i just got the result , thanks ..

Comment: m = df_nonull[cols_list].isna().any(axis=1) | df_nonull[cols_list].eq('').any(axis=1)
df[m]